# Get registry value using C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I am not able to retrieve a software's Installdir. I have tried GetValue and even OpenSubKey but everytime I get a NULL. I am using VS2008, .Net 3.5, 64bit machine, 32bit process setting.

```
private string GetInstallPath()
{
     string keyValue = string.Empty;
     Object key = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\My Company\\My Tool", "Installdir", null);
     ...
}
```

key is returning NULL though there is a valid string there. Equivalent code works in VC++. Please provide your insight to the issue. What am I doing wrong for this supposedly easy task? I cannot use a 'Hive' as it's 4.0 standard. Code level help instead of links would be helpful.

VC++ equivalent

```
HKEY hkey = NULL;
LSTATUS status = RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\My Company\\My Tool\\", 0, KEY_READ, &hkey );

if ( status == ERROR_SUCCESS )
{
  DWORD type;
  char  buff[ 100 ];
  DWORD numBytes = sizeof( buff );
  if ( RegQueryValueExA( hkey, REGISTRY_ENTRY, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE) buff, &numBytes ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
 {
 ...
 }
```

Comment: Added the VC++ equivalent as edit.

Comment: @santra_a I posted working c# that actually will go through and find a definition then will modify the UninstallString to repair an application.  I believe that is what your looking for correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned your machine is x64, and your app is 32 bit unless I misread.  Given your environment the firs thing I would check is to be sure the key exists in the 64 bit node, `HKCU\Software\My Company\...` and not in the 32 bit node `HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\My Company\...`, if your key exists in the 32 bit node, you will need to make sure your app is a 32 bit app, otherwise, you will need to make sure your app is 64 bit or you won't find the key.

The following code worked for me, running in 64 bit and found the key **outside** of the Wow6432Node.  I don't understand why you can't user 'Hive', it works in both 3.5 and 4.0

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\10.0");

if (regKey != null)
{
    object val = regKey.GetValue("FullScreen");
}
```

**Update:**
The following also worked for me, running .NET 3.5, if it's not a platform (x86 vs x64) issue, then it is possibly a **permissions** problem, make sure that the context under which your app is running has access to the registry key (try running the app as administrator or even system)

```
object test = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\10.0", "FullScreen", null);
```

Comment: The first thing you wanted me to check was the point of error. I had to explicitly set my code to 'x86' in Platform target from "Any CPU". This was because the app I was trying to get info of is 32 bit and hence in Wow6432.

Comment: @santra_a glad to hear it got solved, yes, `AnyCPU` will run as 64 bit on a 64 bit system and 32 bit on an x86 system unless the initial entry assembly says otherwise  :)